# CRM ConditionExpression to compare two attributes

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, query-expressions

I'm using Microsoft CRM SDK to retrieve entities. I'm writing `QueryExpression` with `FilterExpression`.

How to write a condition, that takes two attributes in consideration? I want to retrieve entities, for which attribute "Export Date" is less than "Modified On". (ie. all that have been modified since last export).

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();
filter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or;

ConditionExpression condition = new ConditionExpression();
// ...
//how to write this condition? 

filter.AddCondition(condition);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When querying CRM, the following restrictions apply:

- The left-hand side of conditions **must** be a CRM attribute
- The right-hand side of conditions **must** be a constant

In other words, attributes can't be compared directly in a single query.

As a rule of thumb, if your `QueryExpression` can be built as Advanced Find then you're okay, otherwise you're most likely going to need intermediate queries.

Answer (score 3):

In latest version (July 2020), the feature to compare the two attributes of same entity is available in Query Expression (SDK), fetchxml and web api. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/org-service/use-conditionexpression-class?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#column-comparison-using-the-sdk-api)

> This code creates a condition to return only records where the first and last names are the same

```
new ConditionExpression("firstname", ConditionOperator.Equal, true, "lastname");
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible unfortunately. The only way is to retrieve data and build query to retrieved data to get the final result.